# Iterating in drop down through selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do I iterate in drop-down using Selenium Webdriver?

I have a drop-down like B008124/001, B008124/002, B008124/003, B008124/004.

Here I have to select B008124/001 and perform some option like approve. Then I have to select B008124/002 and perform approve the action, and so on.

But the point here is: the mentioned 4 series will not always be the same; it depends on the scenarios and it may vary up to 6, or it maybe 1-2.

[image][image]

Comment: Hi Yukesh, for us is better to get the code instead of screenshot.Then we can modify the code. Because in my case I cannot enlarge screenshot...

Comment: Also when people say "screenshot" they don't normally mean a literal photograph of your monitor...

Answer (score 0):

The solution as you said would be iterating the dropdown with a loop. Since your question was not clear on; is there multiple dropdown or based on previous scenario the count of options are changed I will assume the later one is the question and my answer will be based on that.

What you can do is:

- Try to find every element exists in the dropdown
- Exclude `<option>- Select -</option>`
- Select each element and continue accordingly.

To achieve above you need two things:

- Outer for loop for each element in dropdown.
- Switch-case or if-else for the inner code of loop.

Here is an example code written in Groovy which you might easily adapt the language you use:

```
def iterationForAllElements() {
    List<WebElement> options = webDriver.findElements("selector for option elements")  // Get all available option elements into the WebElement list.
    options.each {option ->                     // This is the loop for each element.
       if(option.getAttribute("value") != 0) {  //Here you exclude option 0 since it's not really an option.

           switch(option.getAttribute("value")) // I assumed for each selection there's different corresponding code should be working. 
              case 1:                           //Otherwise you can use something else rather than switch case.
                 .....          //Here the code will be executed by the value **attribute** of option.
              case 2:
                 .....
              default:
                 .....
       }
    }
}
```

**You also might wanna check if there's any element in the list beforehand to avoid exceptions which might cause false negative results.**

Comment: @yukesh-raj the code above works for you?